# How to calculate PageViews of a site using Alexa stats (formula?)

Tags: php, formula, pageviews, alexa-internet

As simple as it sounds, I just want to know how to calculate the PageViews of a site using Alexa stats. Alexa gives PageViews per-million and reach % of total Internet users, etc. I only want a formula using Alexa data to calculate it. I know, Alexa data is not exact but my problem will be solved by that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(**10909000000** * **alexa_pageView_percent**) / **30** then you'll get the rough estimate of the websites pageview in a day.

Note that it is only a estimate. Its not really accurate!

The **alexa_pageView_percent** is located in alexa traffic summary of every site down to the **traffic stats** tab and **pageviews** tab

Comment: This article gives more accurate calculations, based on fixed data points (e.g. Wikipedia), where both the Alexa rank **and** the page views are known. Data is for 2010, but you can repeat the calculations for any day: http://www.javaneverdie.com/seo/alexa-com-global-page-views-number/

Answer (score 7):

***Hello*** ***Shamit***!

Officially, there's no fixed value - but lets try to derive the ***real*** amount of *visitors*.

For this example, I am using real, yet example values - I am not responsible for mistaken calculations as this may be changing every day (as far as Alexa is able to?).. Okay, lets' begin. ***Edit:*** I just want to add: there's **no** way to at least nearly determine the *real-world* values "precisely".

*What's shown?* 1st column: the day. 2nd column: the alexa rank. 3rd column: the Google Analytics page-view values corresponding to the *Alexa-values*.

Website 1

```
July 12th   0.0008  220403
July 26th   0.00058 266596
August 6th  0.0004  118727
```

Website 2

```
July 12th   0.0002  59628
July 26th   0.0001  72821
August 6th  0.0001  71239
```

Website 3

```
July 12th   0.0001  45178
July 26th   0.0001  37790
August 6th  0.0001  27290
```

Website 4

```
July 12th   0.0007  341092
July 26th   0.0007  431614
August 6th  0.0003  27893
```

Website 5

```
July 12th   0.0001  60716
July 26th   0.0001  54384
August 6th  0.00005 49529
```

From these sample sites, there are obvious changes in consistency. For sample **Website 1** on July 12th there were 220,403 page views giving an Alexa global page views of 0.0008%, but on July 26th 40,000 more page views (266,596) results in Alexa giving a lower percentage of global page views, 0.00058.

Continuing to sample **Website 2**, on July 12th 59,628 resulted in 0.0002% of global page views and two weeks later 10,000 more page views (72,821) gave a lower Alexa percentage, 0.0001%.

Finally in sample **Website 5**‘s data July 12th and July 26th data is consistent with a difference of 6,332 page views (60,716 – 54,384) giving the same Alexa percentage in both cases 0.0001%. However, on August 6th the site page views drops to 49529, approximately 5,000 less page views, but the Alexa percentage halves to 0.00005%, not a relative representation of the change in page views.

Sites gaining an Alexa rank of approximately 0.0001% have a wide range of traffic figures suggesting that the Long Tail effect is apparent in this range of sites which must be densely populated. The lowest traffic I have recorded within the 0.0001% range is **Website 3** with 27,290 page views and the highest is **Website 2** with 72,821 page views. With a difference of almost 50,000 page views the Alexa ranking for sites of this size must be densely populated with large change in ranks from relatively small changes in page views.

However, sites with page views within this range (27,290 to 72,821 page views) do not have corresponding Alexa global page views percentages. **Website 4** on August 6th fits within the 0.0001% range from Google analytic page view data (27,893 page views), but Alexa gave a global page views percentage of **0.0003%**, 0.0002% higher, revealing clear inaccuracies in Alexa ranking. Due to these inaccuracies I feel it is impossible to attempt to calculate the real world value in page views of a reach of 0.0001% from Alexa.

Comment: Is there anything wrong or yet unclear, as you didn't accept it, yet?

Comment: I have accepted the answer. Thank you for reminding. BTW, my name is wrong. It's Shamit not Shamitt. But that's not the reason for not accepting your answer. Thank you again for your detailed reply.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here (http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm) is described a way to make a traffic estimation based on the alexa rank.  Basically, **the author has offered an exponential function, not linear or polynomial**.

There is also a web service which aggregated alexa ranks + real data and made the calculations: http://www.rank2traffic.com/