# Alexa Rank to Traffic Estimation Formula

Tags: php, rank, traffic, alexa-internet

Anybody have some idea how we can convert alexa Rank to estimate the daily visitors of a website. previous we can easily do this by Alexa Site Reach percentage but alexa reach is no more available. previous i am using this forumula

```
$visitors = (200000000*$reach)/100
```

how can we estimate now with alexa rank?

Comment: Why waste time with Alexa? It can be **easily faked** and I'd suggest looking for an alternative. Also, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485739/how-to-calculate-pageviews-of-a-site-using-alexa-stats-formula) question, if you haven't already. I know it'd old, but it contains some information that *may* be useful to you.

Answer (score 13):

This article contains more precise formula and online converter "Alexa Rank -> Monthly Traffic" - http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm

Monthly Visitors = 104,943,144,672 x AlexaRank ^ -1.008

Answer (score 4):

I think according to Alexa rule, the multiplication between monthly visitors and Alexa Rank is a constant, which is equal to 1x10^11 (1,00,000,000,000). So, (Alexa Rank) x (Monthly Visitors) = 1,00,000,000,000.
This formula can be used to roughly estimate Alexa Rank/Monthly Visitors. For example, if AR = 1000 then MV = 1x10^8 (1,00,000,000) and vice versa. You can verify this by using a tool provided at http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm

Answer (score 2):

This service: http://www.rank2traffic.com/ gives traffic estimation based on the formula given here: http://netberry.co.uk/alexa-rank-explained.htm

Answer (score 0):

Once you determine a formula for trafic calculation, you may use this online database to get old alexa rank data: http://alexarankdb.com/

Comment: Don't want to downvote you into negatives, but for the benefit of other readers, the linked-to site is bogus—it was off by 20x for my properties.

Comment: The numbers there are alexa ranks, not visits or sessions.